# Laravel 6 redirect is showing full path to file when is used in middleware

Tags: laravel, url, redirect, routes, filepath

I have problem with laravel. I created middleware which redirects me using route to main page.
Problem is that when I use redirect in controllers i will get url like this example.com/, but when I use redirect in middleware I will get url like this example.com/project/public/. Why is that? And how can I get url like when i use controllers (I want this: example.com/)
(I have .htaccess configured to use public folder as rootfolder)

Middleware code (result is: example.com/project/public/)

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    return redirect(route('main'));//this is route using name
}
```

Controller code (result is: example.com/)

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
        return redirect(route('main'));
}
```

Route looks like this

```
Route::get('/', 'MyController@main')->name("main");
```

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: Controller code and middleware code are exactly the same, is that correct?

Comment: Make sure that in your `.env` file the `APP_URL` is set to the correct URL, and then you can also use `redirect()->route('main');` instead of passing the full URL to the redirect function.

Comment: Yeah, thats right. It's same. But with different result.

Comment: APP_URL is set to correct URL

Comment: redirect()->route('main'); does same result